# how can i get a CSV file upload request from client side and parse the data to upload in mySql database in nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'd like to be able to upload a file and import that to MySQL. I've installed a server to do so. However, I do not know how to upload and process the CSV file.

Comment: please post code, add info on which libraries you are using to accomplish this. Also add examples of things you have tried which (presumably) did not work. Make sure to keep the example as minimal as possible without removing any relevant information.

Comment: I have restated the question.

Comment: actually i have created a table in client side and parsed all the data from csv file and stored in that table,now i have to upload this data to MySQL database and dynamically i have to create the table schema in database

Answer (score 0):

There are already a node module which you can use **csv-parse**

You can read you file using **fs** module and after reading file you can parse it using **csv-parse**

here are the links https://csv.js.org/ , [how to import a csv file to mysql using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638569/how-to-import-a-csv-file-to-mysql-using-node-js)

Thank You